# MVC 3 View with partial view and Ajax form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Here is my quandary.  I have an MVC 3 web site, and I have a page that needs to contain a sub-form, if you will, to collect some data related to my model.  I have successfully created a partial view that contains the markup and I am rendering this properly.  However, the input button in the partial view doesn't seem to be doing much of anything.  Here is the form in the partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddProductCustomField", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "addCustomFieldView" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomFieldId, new SelectList(Model.CustomFields, "FieldId", "FieldName"), "-- Select One --", new { @class = "int_std_select" })<text>&nbsp;</text>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomFieldValue, new { @class = "int_std_textbox" })
    <input type="submit" value="Add Custom Field" /><br />
}
```

"AddProductCustomField" is the name of my controller method that I want to handle this form post.  However, clicking the submit button does nothing.  I even popped open Fiddler to see if a request was getting eaten and nothing.  I've included all the appropriate JavaScript files for this page (MicrosoftAjax, MicrosoftMvcAjax and the unobtrusive JavaScript).  I'm stumped.

Please let me know if I need to provide more info.  Thanks much, this has been stumping me for days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned sub-form. Do you literally mean you are nesting forms? This is not supported in HTML, so I would think that's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Crap, you're probably right.  Don't know of any other way to accomplish what I want.  In Web Forms it was easy, just wrap the whole thing in an UpdatePanel and be done with it.  Looks like I'll have to rethink the solution.  Thanks, Ken.